# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class kotlin.UByte

Tags: android, kotlin

I got the following exception when my application reach this code.

```
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
fun fromByteArray(result: UByteArray): DeviceData {
    val action = result[0].and(0xFFu).toUInt() // Line 75
    ...
```

My exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
    Process: org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.samples.androidstudio, PID: 23459
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class kotlin.UByte: int kotlin.UByte.compareTo(java.lang.Object) failed to verify: int kotlin.UByte.compareTo(java.lang.Object): [0x6] invoke-super/virtual can't be used on private method int kotlin.UByte.compareTo-7apg3OU(byte) (declaration of 'kotlin.UByte' appears in /data/app/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.samples.androidstudio-Y5EgyM_pfv77cE-5gEVlZw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at kotlin.UByte.constructor-impl(UByte.kt:15)
        at kotlin.UByteArray.get-impl(UByteArray.kt:26)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.samples.androidstudio.repository.DeviceData.fromByteArray-GBYM_sE(DeviceRepository.kt:75)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.samples.androidstudio.BluetoothInputThread.run(BluetoothInputThread.kt:29)
```

Has anybody experienced something like this?